# ios, tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath not called

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)
```

is getting called and returning non zero value.

but the following code isn't getting called.. why?

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

tableView is initially 0 size, and supposed to grow dynamically, would it be the cause of this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

cellForRowAtIndexPath will not be called if tableView's size is zero!
And you must not keep any logical part in that method. You must use that method only for updating the ui, no more.